# Copy camera viewpoint using open3d gui

Tags: python-3.9, open3d

Open3d's easy `draw_geometries` utility makes it possible to copy & paste camera parameters to restore a certain view point after it has been changed. It seems like this functionality would also be available when using the `SceneWidget` and its `Open3DScene` high level scene. However I have not figured out a way to mimic this behavior.

Copying and pasting a viewpoint from `draw_geometries` onto notepad reveals this information:

`boundingbox_max`, `boundingbox_min`, `field_of_view`, `front`, `lookat`, `up`, `zoom`

In order for it to have the same effect using the `SceneWidget` I would have to somehow obtain this information from the scene's camera, create a copy, and then load it later when it is needed. Nevertheless, I cannot access the above properties explicitly through the camera object, nor have I found a way to set them (assuming I already have them).

The next "obvious" solution would be the camera class's [copy_from](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.rendering.Camera.html#open3d.visualization.rendering.Camera.copy_from) method, which sounds great, except I am unable to instantiate the `Camera` class in order to use it.

How can I achieve this save & restore viewpoint effect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to figure out two solutions. I could not figure out a way to instantiate the `Camera` class in order to use the `copy_from` method. A neat way around this problem is to create a second `SceneWidget` that will not be shown and simply act as a buffer. Using the `SceneWidget.Open3DScene`'s camera property it is possible to copy to and from the main scene's camera. In summation, bind a key that saves the main camera to the buffer scene's camera, and another key to restore it.

This solution however only allows copying and pasting viewpoints for a single runtime of the application, so we need to save the camera parameters to a file. Using the default camera movement pattern, it appears that only the camera itself moves and rotates around the object. Through the camera's `get_model_matrix()` method, we get a `4x4` matrix. The last column corresponds to the camera position and the first `3x3` matrix represents a composite rotation. We extract and save the following information

```
m = camera.get_model_matrix()
rot = model[:3, :3]
pos = model[:3, 3]
```

An then, in order to restore the viewpoint we use the `SceneWidget`'s `look_at(point, camera_position, camera_up)`, as follows:

```
camera_dir = np.dot(rot, np.array([[0],[0],[-1]])).squeeze()
scene.look_at(pos + camera_dir, pos, np.array([0,1,0]))
```

Since by default the camera looks towards the screen (-z) we multiply the direction vector by the rotation matrix we save earlier, and obtain a point on the direction vector as `pos + camera_dir`.

Warning! This does not account for the direction of the up vector. If the viewpoint you want to save is upside down, the up vector should be `(0,-1,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and building on @VlassisFo answer, I solved it this way:

Save the model:

```
cam = vis.scene.camera.get_model_matrix()
fov = vis.scene.camera.get_field_of_view()
```

Restore its parameter to another view:

```
m = cam
rot = m[:3, :3]
pos = m[:3, 3]
camera_dir = np.dot(rot, np.array([[0],[0],[-1]])).squeeze()
camera_up = np.dot(rot, np.array([[0],[1],[0]])).squeeze()
vis.setup_camera(fov, pos + camera_dir, pos, camera_up)
```